# Получение html кода страницы с помощью WebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser

Здравствуйте. Возникла проблемка... Пишу программку одну и мне понадобилось получить html код страницы. Получаю я его через `webBrowser` (знаю, что можно по другому, но нужно именно через него) и записываю в `richTextBox`. Все было нормально до определенного момента, когда я запустив программу не получил html код....

```
        webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://site.ru/");
        richTextBox1.AppendText(webBrowser1.DocumentText);
```

Вот код, который я выполняю. В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Наверное надо документ текст брать убедившись что браузер всё загрузил...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подпишись на событие DocumentCompleted в WebBrowser

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(webBrowser1.DocumentText);
        }
```